# Can't push my view controller when I select a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using Objective-C. I want to push a new vier controller when I select a table view cell. This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    detailViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
    //something
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

I have a detail view controller in my storyBoard and set its storyboard ID "deatilVC". But when I select a table view cell, the simulator freezes. Someone can help me?

Comment: Why not use segues with storyboard? (`ctrl`+drag from the cell to the view controller and you can choose whether to segue either when selected or when the accessory button tapped).

Comment: put a breakpoint on the [self.navig .. line, and check that the vc object is not nil - it might not have instantiated properly for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Take one navigation controller and make the current controller from where your didSelectRowAtIndexPath will call to it's root controller in storyboard. Check the following example.

[image]

And then drag with right click of mouse to your current controller and make it "root view controller" just like below:

[image]

Build and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

make sure "self.navigationController" is not nil and "vc" is not nil